# Superuser website design flaw

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, superuser

Just noticed this on superuser. Refreshed the page, still buggy. Using newest Firefox :-)

[image]

Comment: Why are you posting here and not on its own meta?

Comment: Didn't create an account there yet and didn't know every channel has its own meta. Can you move or suggest what I do now?

Comment: Is that the newest stable Firefox, or newest nightly? Which extensions do you have installed, and does it work if you disable them?

Comment: Non repro with Firefox 21 you probably use beta version which isn't supported by Stack Exchange. However while testing, found bug with IE10: http://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ykwt.png

Comment: lol even the same question... ok it's a duplicate. this guy also posted on this channel :D please don't downvote. just close

Comment: Firefox 21, release channel, only default plugins+firebug

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn it's not just SU, it's SF as well. Hence the reason for posting here (and it's dupe is here too).

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I do reporduce with FF21